# Libdx.Texture doesn't contain a 0 argument constructor

Tags: java, libgdx

ok guys, I'm making a character editor in libgdx, it's basically and editor for the animation hitboxes, so far it works, it saves a json file, but whenever I click load, it crashes.

I know the error refers to libgdx.texture doens't contain a 0 argument constructor, but I wonder what can I do.

```
Exception in thread "LWJGL Application" com.badlogic.gdx.utils.SerializationException: Class cannot be created (missing no-arg constructor): com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.Texture
Serialization trace:
keyTable (com.badlogic.gdx.utils.ObjectSet)
textures (com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.g2d.TextureAtlas)
atlas (hitbox.Animations)
animation_list (hitbox.Character)
```

Here it's my code:

```
public void Save(String s)
    {
        Json json = new Json();
        String character_string = json.toJson(character);
        FileHandle file = Gdx.files.absolute(s);

        file.writeString(character_string, false);
    }

    public void Load(String s)
    {
        FileHandle file = Gdx.files.absolute(s);

        if (file.exists())
        {
            String character_string = file.readString();
            Json json = new Json();
            character = json.fromJson(Character.class, character_string);
        }
    }

public class Character {

    public List<Animations> animation_list;

    public Character()
    {
        animation_list = new ArrayList<Animations>();
        animation_list.add(new Animations());
    }

}
public class Animations {

public List<Frame> frame;
public String name_of_animation, path_to_atlas;
public int index, last_frame, number_frames;
public TextureAtlas atlas;
public Animation animation;
//"data/ATHENA/walking.atlas" path to atlas

    public Animations()
    {
        frame = new ArrayList<Frame>();
        frame.add(new Frame());
        name_of_animation = "null name";
        path_to_atlas = "null path";
        index = 0;
        last_frame = 0;
        number_frames = 0;
    }

    public void AddAtlas(String name)
    {
        FileHandle handle = Gdx.files.absolute(name);
        if (handle.exists())
        {
            atlas = new TextureAtlas(handle);
            animation = new Animation(1/15f, atlas.getRegions());
        }
    }


}
```

Comment: Somewhat unclear what you are asking. You read your job and get a file path. You use that path in the Texture constructor.

Comment: @MennoGouw Libgdx texture doens't have an emtpy constructor, that's my problem. It's not my code the one that produces the error but rather libgdx library.

Comment: The solution to your problem is to not serialize textures - customize the serialization of your class to not serialize the texture, but rather the information required to recreate the texture (the atlas file path, region name, whatever).

Comment: Ahhhh you are trying to serialise the Texture itself?  Why? Like I said you serialise a string and create the Texture from that.

Comment: how i approached this kind of problem was all my texture i wanted to serialized were in a array of textures and i serialized the index of the texture from that array so i it helped me reducing the file size and at load time i use to serialize de-serialize the file and get current texture on basis of the array index